# Infinite series expansion of $\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion

> Prove the formula $$\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1}
>  \left ( \frac{\sin x}{2} \right )^{2n} $$ where $C_n = \displaystyle
>  \frac{1}{n+1}{{2n}\choose{n}}$.

I tried to use the Taylor series of sine function to obtain an infinite sum, but the exponent $2n$ is difficult to deal with.

Comment: $sin^2\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1-cosx}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-sin^2x})$, which can be expanded into an infinite series in $sin^2x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Note that Catalan numbers $(C_n)_n$ have a nice [generating function](http://planetmath.org/generatingfunctionforthecatalannumbers):
for $|4z|\leq 1$,
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} C_n z^n = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$
Now note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_{n-1}
 \left ( \frac{\sin x}{2} \right )^{2n}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_{n}
 \left (\frac{\sin^2 x}{4} \right )^{n}.$$
Can you take it from here?